# Make emacs org-mode deadlines and scheduled blocked tasks visible in agenda view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here are the relevant parts of my .emacs

```
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-enforce-todo-checkbox-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

When I visit my agenda view I want to see tasks which are scheduled or have a deadline (even if they are blocked by another task and are therefor stricly speaking rightly invisible).

Currently those tasks are not visible whilst they are being blocked by other tasks.

I would however prefer that an exception be made for these tasks which have been scheduled or given a deadline and that they be made visibile so that I maintain active awareness of them.

Answer (score 3):

This could be accomplished by splitting off the scheduled and deadline tasks with a custom agenda view. Only scheduled and deadline items would be shown in the first block, and the setting to make blocked tasks invisible can be applied to uniquely to a the second block. For example:

```
;; Retain your default settings
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-enforce-todo-checkbox-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks t)

;; Create the custom agenda view
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
 '(("c" 
    "Agenda to show deadlines & hide blocked"
    (
     (agenda "" 
            ((org-agenda-entry-types '(:deadline :scheduled))))
     (tags-todo "-TODO=\"DONE\""
          ((org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'deadline 'scheduled)
           (org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)))
))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because of your setting:

```
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

?

Comment: Absolutely, yes it is. However, although generally that makes sense, in the case of deadlines and scheduled tasks I need to know they are coming up. Perhaps there is some way to set an exception?