# Org-mode: How to show blocked tasks in custom agenda overriding global settings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I set `org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks` globally to `'invisible`

```
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

And I want to override `org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks` for a particular custom agenda. I have tried,

```
("B" "BLOCKED"
    ((tags-todo "+TODO/!"
        ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Blocked tasks")
         (org-dim-blocked-tasks nil))))
)
```

But the tasks are still not showing in the agenda.

Is it possible blocked tasks to be visible in particular custom agenda, while being invisible globally? In other words, is it possible to override the global setting for `org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks` in custom agenda?

I found another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846732/make-emacs-org-mode-deadlines-and-scheduled-blocked-tasks-visible-in-agenda-view), sadly without an answer. And also this [question](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-04/msg00092.html) in the mailing list, which I can't fully understand the solution.

If that is not possible, what would be the best work around?